# Nuxt 3 JS middleware Sidebase callback

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I don't know why, I have cookies and I also set expr.. but it always calls back to the login page...
cookies have been stored in the application in the console. but when I refresh the page in the dashboard, the callback goes to the login page again.

[My Repo](https://github.com/wildy13/Nuxt3)

Btw, I'm using sidebase.io module, I'm new to this module.. I hope you guys can help with my problem

I hope, this isn't another callback